# Changing my URL from "../page.html" to "../page/" with URL rewrites

Tags: url, url-rewriting

How can I rewrite my url changing my default prefix .html or .php in / ?

For example look here: http://www.anderssonwise.com/studio/vision/

I've found this tut but nothing happen:
http://www.spencerdrager.com/2010/02/07/hide-php-extension-in-url-using-htaccess/

Comment: And you are running Apache with mod_rewrite enabled?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use URL Rewrites, which is why Krister asked you if you have mod_rewrite enabled.  It's not the simplest thing in the world to do but here's a pretty good tutorial:

http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Answer (score 0):

You create a folder, in this example, /page/ and within that folder create index.html and then you'll be able to access the page like: http://domain.com/page/

Comment: You know I was just typing the same answer, but then tried with a directory on my computer and it didn't automatically bring index.html I think he needs to also configure his server to give index.html if only the directory was given